# zip file upload from android using httpurlconnection

Tags: android, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2

Getting  "Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete" exception on server side while uploading zip file from client side using httpurlconnection

Below is the upload code

```
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-   data; boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-GB,en-US; q=0.8,en; q=0.6");
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());


            outputStream.writeBytes(boundary + LINE_FEED);
            String [] q = fileName.split("/");
            int ind = q.length-1;
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"logs\"; filename=\"" +q[ind] + "\""+ LINE_FEED);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/octet-stream "+LINE_FEED);

            outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);

            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytes_read = -1;
            while((bytes_read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);
            outputStream.writeBytes(boundary);

            responseMsg = connection.getResponseMessage();
```

while uploading same file using postman, file gets uploaded successfully